# Error Number: 1064 in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am getting this error when ever i am uploading a file and storing details in the database using codeigniter

here is my controller

```
    public function sugsn_up()
{
    if ( $this->session->userdata('login_state') == FALSE )
        $this->load->view('faculty/facultylog1_view');
    else
    {
    $config['upload_path'] = './suggestion/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|docx|txt';
    $config['max_size'] = '10000000';
    $emp_id=$this->session->userdata('emp_id');          
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $tname='subject_master';
        $res['sub']=$this->faculty_model->return_rec($tname);
        $tname='course_master';
        $res['crse']=$this->faculty_model->return_rec($tname);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('faculty/up_sugsn', $error,$res);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $path=base_url().'attendence/'.$data['upload_data']['file_name'];
        $sdata=array('sug_id'=>NULL,
                 'emp_id'=>$emp_id,
                 'sug_name'=>$_POST['sugsn_name'],
                 'course_id'=> $_POST['cid'],
                 'sub_id'=> $_POST['sid'],
                 'link'=>$path
                 );
                 $this->faculty_model->sugsn_up($sdata);
        $this->load->view('faculty/upload_success', $data);
    }
    }
}
```

and this is my model

```
    public function sugsn_up($sdata)
{
    $this->db->insert('suggestion _master',$sdata);
}
```

My suggestion _master table has 6 filds

Field   Type      Collation
    sug_id    bigint(20)
    emp_id    bigint(20)
    sug_name  text
    course_id bigint(20)
    sub_id    bigint(20)
    link      text

and i am getting this error

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '_master (`sug_id`, `emp_id`, `sug_name`, `course_id`, `sub_id`, `link`) VALUES (' at line 1

INSERT INTO `suggestion` _master (`sug_id`, `emp_id`, `sug_name`, `course_id`, `sub_id`, `link`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'test', '1', '1', 'file_link[soflo shows error when posting the exact link]')

Filename: C:\wamp\www\CMC\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Can you find any thing wrong here?please help

Thanks and regards
Dibyendu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `suggestion _master`..
```

Add backticks for table and column names if they contain empty spaces,but empty spaces in table names are not OK.

Comment: thank you so much i didn't notice the empty space, its working now.